# File Transfer via TCP socket Pipe in C++

Tags: file, sockets, tcp, pipe, transfer

I have a question regarding creating a pipe of sequential sockets to forward a TCP flow over N-Hops path (S - - - > M1 - - - > M2 - - - > M3 - - - > D ). The goal is for S to send the file over a TCP socket to D. Therefore, All nodes M1, M2 and M3 will operate in two modes, server and client except S and D, which will operate in one mode only.

My question is that: can I create a pipe of sockets to form this path so as M1 receives the first packet from S, it will froward it directly to M2 and so on (i.e., no waiting on any of the M's to receive the entire file, JUST SEND WHAT EVER YOU receive Immediately )? And based on the available Client/Server TCP socket model, what is required to perform this task if doable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can... but you'll need to program each machine with an event loop that does that (i.e. the sockets layer won't do it for you).

The way I'd do it is to have each machine run an event loop around select(), using a couple of non-blocking sockets (one for incoming data, one for outgoing data).   Each process would have a small (8kB?) internal buffer that it uses to temporarily store some of the data that it wants to forward.

Then your select-loop would operate on these rules:

1) Whenever the internal-buffer is less-than-full, tell select() you want to be notified when the incoming-data-socket has data ready for you to read.

2) Whenever the internal-buffer is more-than-empty, tell select() you want to be notified when the outgoing-data-socket has buffer space ready for you to write to.

3) Whenever select() indicates to you that the incoming-data-socket has data ready for you to read, read some data from the incoming-data-socket into your temporary local buffer.  (The amount you read will be limited by the amount of data available on the incoming-data-socket and the amount of space available in your local buffer, whichever is smaller)

4) Whenever select() indicates to you that the outgoing-data-socket has buffer space to write to, write some data to the outgoing-data-socket from your temporary local buffer.  (The amount you write will be limited by the amount of data present the incoming-data-socket and the amount of space the outgoing socket can currently accept, whichever is smaller)

Given the above logic, bytes would flow from each node to the next in a fairly pipelined manner.

(error handling and setting up the sockets via socket(), connect() or bind()/listen()/accept() is not described here, but that would be necessary also)

Comment: Can we make this job as a one script that runs both modules, client and server at ones? It seems to complicated to me as not an expert in c programming! Can you help in setting the main body from which I can start?

Comment: You can, but you'll have to do your own C programming, or hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: Why using fork() is not the right choice? The server will fork the first child for incoming data and and the second for outgoing data while waiting for a new connections to come in (i.e., any node can be involved in many paths as an intermediate as possible).

Comment: I find another way to do non-blocking sockets called Libevent; do you know which one will provide higher performance "less delay", Libevent or the select() multiplexing?